Hoop, Hoop, Hoop, Hoop, Eye-Eye-Eye-Eye
The Horrible Histories song "Learn Your Hieroglyphics" mentions a fanmade number system. Numbers are written as a sum of 10's ("hoops") and 1's ("eyes"), for example 99 is
hoop hoop hoop hoop hoop hoop hoop hoop hoop eye eye eye eye eye eye eye eye eye

. Then, I thought, why not turn this into some sort of binary code?
Your programs should take a nonnegative integer as input.
Then, it should create a string of alternating 1's and 0's, with each group of the same digit corresponding to a digit in the number, in bijective decimal. This is so every number has a unique representation.
Examples:
0 -> empty string
1 -> 1
2 -> 11
9 -> 111111111
10 -> 1111111111
11 -> 10
19 -> 1000000000
20 -> 10000000000
99 -> 111111111000000000
100 -> 1111111110000000000
110 -> 11111111110000000000
111 -> 101
123 -> 100111
4567 -> 1111000001111110000000

Then, the strings are interpreted as a binary number, then that number is outputted.
Examples:
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 3
9 -> 511
10 -> 1023
11 -> 2
19 -> 512
20 -> 1024
99 -> 261632
100 -> 523264
110 -> 1047552
111 -> 5
123 -> 39
4567 -> 3940224

This is code-golf, so fewest bytes wins!

In its current form, this challenge looks like a chameleon challenge to me, as the trickiest part may actually be to perform the bijective decimal conversion for languages that don't have a built-in. You should probably emphasize and explain bijective decimal.

Related

Charcoal, 31 bytes
ＮθＷθ«⊞υ∨﹪θχχ≔÷⊖θχθ»Ｉ⍘⭆⮌υ×§10κι²

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
ＮθＷθ«⊞υ∨﹪θχχ≔÷⊖θχθ»

Input the number and convert it to little-endian bijective base 10.
Ｉ⍘⭆⮌υ×§10κι²

Create a string alternating between 1s and 0s and convert that from base 2 to decimal.

This unfortunately outputs nothing instead of 0 for edge case $n=0$.

@KevinCruijssen Ugh, that's a bug in Charcoal; it's crashing in BaseString looking for a sign. Here's a workaround for until I get around to patching it.

JavaScript (Node.js), 41 bytes
f=x=>x?(f(--x/10|0)+(e^=1)<<1+x%10)-e:e=0

Try it online!

05AB1E, 21 18 bytes
[D_#<T‰`ˆ}TÞ¯R>×JC

Port of @Neil's Charcoal answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
-3 bytes thanks to @Neil
For a language that's literally called 'Base' (when interpret as hexadecimal and converted to base-64), its lack of a bijective-base builtin is a bit disappointing for this challenge.. So things are done manually using the same approach as the Charcoal answer.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
[          # Start an infinite loop:
 D         #  Duplicate the current integer
           #  (which will use the implicit input-integer in the first iteration)
  _        #  Pop the copy, and check whether it's 0
   #       #  Pop and if it's 0: stop the infinite loop
    <      #  Decrease the integer by 1
     T‰    #  Divmod by 10: [n//10,n%10]
       `   #  Pop and push both values separated to the stack
        ˆ  #  Pop the top n%10 and add it to the global array
}T         # After the infinite loop: push 10
  Þ        # Convert it to an infinitely cycling digit-list: [1,0,1,0,1,0,...]
   ¯       # Push the global array
    R      # Reverse it
     >     # Increase each inner digit by 1
      ×    # Repeat the [1,0,1,0,1,0,...] those amount of times
       J   # Join it together
        C  # Convert it from a binary-string to a base-10 integer
           # (which is output implicitly as result)


18 bytes. (I could also have used this approach in my Charcoal answer; it has the same byte count there though because it wastes bytes to decrement and modulo the value in separate statements.)

By the way, I appreciated the Base trivia; I don't remember seeing that before.

Setanta, 93 92 86 83 bytes
gniomh(x){t:=0f:=1nuair-a x{t=f-t-1x-=1le i idir(-1,x%10){t+=f f*=2}x//=10}toradh t}

try-setanta.ie link
Explanation
gniomh(x){t:=0f:=1nuair-a x{t=f-t-1x-=1le i idir(-1,x%10){t+=f f*=2}x//=10}toradh t}­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
          t:=0                                                                        >-- ‎⁡Cumulative result
              f:=1                                                                    >-- ‎⁢Next bit to set
                  nuair-a x{                                              }           >-- ‎⁣Iterate for each digit of the bijective representation: while x > 0...
                            t=f-t-1                                                   >-- ‎⁤Invert the existing bits of the cumulative result
                                   x-=1                                               >-- ‎⁢⁡Subtract x by 1
                                       le i idir(-1,x%10){         }                  >-- ‎⁢⁢Do the following x % 10 + 1 times:
                                                          t+=f                        >-- ‎⁢⁣Set next bit of result
                                                               f*=2                   >-- ‎⁢⁤Update next bit
                                                                    x//=10            >-- ‎⁣⁡Divide x by 10
                                                                           toradh t   >-- ‎⁣⁢Return the result


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Vyxal 3, 13 12 9 bytes
₀ḋ:κḃ$YfB

Try it Online!

Jelly, 7 bytes
ḃ⁵Jx$ḂḄ

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer and yields a non-negative integer.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
ḃ⁵Jx$ḂḄ - Link: non-negative integer, N
 ⁵      - ten
ḃ       - convert {N} to bijective base {ten}
    $   - last two links as a monad - f(B=that):
  J     -   indices {B} -> [1,2,...,#digits]
   x    -   {B} times {that}    -> [1,1,...,2,2,...,3,3,...,...]
     Ḃ  - least significant bit -> [1,1,...,0,0,...,1,1,...,...]
      Ḅ - convert {that} from binary


Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 65 bytes
{:2(.&(my&g={$_??g(+^-$_ div 10)~($!+^=1)x+^-$_%10+1!!~($!=0)}))}

Attempt This Online!
